# Python Import from Parent Folder

Tags: python, import

EDIT: directory structure added as per comment

I've read the "similar questions" and tried their suggestions but am still stuck. I want to take some code that works in Jupyter and run it from my console.

The code is loaded into Jupyer like so: `%load ../linked_list/linked_list.py`

However both these attempt fail:

```
from linked_list import *
from ...linked_list import *
```

All the parent directories (two levels) have `__init__.py` in them.

I find python imports very confusing. What am I missing here please?

The relevant part of the directory structure is below. I wish to import into `add_reverse.py`.

```
C:.
|   .gitattributes
|   .gitignore
|   CONTRIBUTING.md
|   LICENSE
|   README.md
|   requirements.txt
|   __init__.py
|
|
+---linked_lists
|   |   __init__.py
|   |
|   +---add_reverse
|   |   |   add_reverse.py  ----- IMPORT HERE PLEASE
|   |   |   add_reverse_challenge.ipynb
|   |   |   add_reverse_solution.ipynb
|   |   |   test_add_reverse.py
|   |   |   __init__.py
|   |   |
|   |   \---.ipynb_checkpoints
|   |           add_reverse_challenge-checkpoint.ipynb
|   |
|   |
|   +---linked_list
|   |   |   linked_list.py
|   |   |   linked_list_challenge.ipynb
|   |   |   linked_list_challenge.py
|   |   |   linked_list_solution.ipynb
|   |   |   test_linked_list.py
|   |   |   __init__.py
|   |   |
|   |   +---.ipynb_checkpoints
|   |   |       linked_list_challenge-checkpoint.ipynb
|   |   |       linked_list_solution-checkpoint.ipynb
|   |   |
|   |   \---__pycache__
|   |           linked_list_challenge.cpython-37.pyc
|   |
```

Comment: You should show the full directory structure, with all the files (`__init__.py` and others), *and* the file that contains the import statements.

Comment: Is the program being started via running `add_reverse.py`, or it's another script?

Comment: add_reverse.py needs the class definition from linked_list.py to ether be run directky or be imported into test_add_reverse.py